# pipewire mod.x11-bell: XOpenDisplay() failed

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, pipewire

I'm getting an error(twice during boot):

`pipewire[1704]: mod.x11-bell: XOpenDisplay() failed`

I wonder why it appears.

- I tried to configure the [PipeWire X11 bell module](https://docs.pipewire.org/page_module_x11_bell.html).
- tried to add the `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`

```
    .include /etc/pulse/default.pa
    
    `# audible bell
    load-sample-lazy bell-window-system /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga
    load-module module-x11-bell
```

I have Debian Bookworm with the kernel version:

`uname -a`

```
Linux XXX 6.0.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.12-1 (2022-12-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Nothing worked.  Does anyone have idea how to fix it?

Answer (score -2):

If your audio is working fine, then you can safely ignore it, [apparently](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/no-module-libpipewire-module-x11-bell-was-found/33945).

As far as I understand, this is related to the PipeWire X11 bell module loading before X does and/or to not using the `nofail` flag. It seems that `mod.x11-bell` [crashes when used without X](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/2239), but Gnome appears to reload it later.

I can't say for all DEs, but in my case GNOME seems to take care of it at a later stage in the startup process. My audio works fine, and if I run `pw-cli list-objects | grep libpipewire-module` after startup, the X11 bell module shows up as loaded. I'm on Wayland, but it's all the same on X.

Finally, you should consider whether you need the module at all. Apparently, the `x11-bell` was moved into a separate module because [most people didn't want it](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/2962).

EDIT: added links and more info

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would like to know the reason behind the error message.  The error message should not appear on arbitrary places.

Comment: I've added some more info and links to the answer. As I understand it, the module needs X in some form. PipeWire usually gets started before X (or Xwayland), so when it loads the bell module, it fails. GNOME seems to take care of it later. You can also set the `nofail` flag in the module's config to stop it from failing and clear the logs.

Answer (score -2):

Note: none will be needed. The "libpipewire-module-x11-bell" module is just a sound signal ( bell ) played when the pipewire is triggered. It's that little bell that rings on startup. Not to be confused with the bell that sounds when the GUI is available (on systems like Linux Mint-Cinnamon, or POP OS). If the error notice is annoying, or filling the log notices with useless notices, it is possible to disable the system request to ring the bell that no longer exists, and thus get rid of error notices. See how at: https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/pipewire-pulse-how-to-change-sound-sample-bell-window-system/70683

Comment: Instead of directing to another Web resource, you should summarise how to disable this _in your answer_, so that it's useful when the linked site isn't available.  Please [edit] your answer to be complete in itself (you can still keep the link as a reference to show the source of your information).

Answer (score -2):

Additional:
https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/pipewire-pulse-how-to-change-sound-sample-bell-window-system/70683 shows how to change the sound signal, with whatever is in the sounds folder of your system. *IF* it's still working, of course!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/445413)